# jQuery doesn't let me use href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
$(".container").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentBox = $(this).siblings(".map").toggleClass("active");
    $(".map.active").not(currentBox).removeClass("active");
});
```

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

[image]

Because of this i cant use `href` anymore.
I use the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)to show more links.

Comment: I don't see href in your pasted code.  And in your image you are putting href on divs and p tags.  href isn't a valid attribute on div and p tags.  Why are you trying to use div and p tags like <a> tags?

Comment: e.preventDefault() stops the default event of an element, in the case of an <a> element, that would be directing the link. You should remove that line to allow the default event to occur.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're trying to use `div`'s and `p`'s like anchors (`a`). href [is not a valid attribute of `div`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) or `p`.

If you're trying to store data in the `div` and `p` tags, use `data-href=""` in conjunction with `window.open()`

Based on the limited code provided, my guess is that you're trying to do something like this:

```
$(".container").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const $this = $(this);

    $(".map.active").removeClass("active");
    $this.siblings(".map").toggleClass("active");

    let href = $this.attr("data-href");

    // Open a new window
    window.open(href);

    // OR

    // Navigate without opening new window
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Or, you could skip the jQuery all together an just use anchor tags as they're designed to be used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery for get any attribute of elements. So if you want to use `href`, just do:

```
var new_location = $('a').attr('href');
```

So you can do anything by click on `a` tag and at the least redirect to `href` path by:

```
window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
```

**Note:** `$(this)` point to current clicked `a` tag. So you have something like this:

```
$(".container").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentBox = $(this).siblings(".map").toggleClass("active");
    $(".map.active").not(currentBox).removeClass("active");

    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing one of the reasons you got a downvote is because code-only answers are not very useful.  Some explanation of what you did / why it solves the problem is far more helpful.

Comment: This answer is generic and does not point out the real problem with the OP's code, i.e., there isn't a single `a` in his code. Additionally, why the the OP want to capture the click on an `a`, prevent the default behavior, and then continue with the page navigation?